# get current record while modifying fields with GridFieldDetailForm

Tags: silverstripe

first off all, I'm using SilverStripe 3.2 RC1.

I need to modify the shown fields of a gridfield item if you click on it. To accomplish this I'm modifying the 'GridFieldDetailForm' fields like that

```
$bundleGridForm = $bundleGridConfig->getComponentByType('GridFieldDetailForm');

$detailFormFields = FieldList::create(
  TabSet::create(
    'Root',
    Tab::create(
      'Haupt-Inhalt',
      CheckboxSetField::create(
        'ManyMany[AvailableVariations]',
        'Verfügbare Variationen',
        $HELP-NEEDED-HERE->VariationItems()->map()->toArray()
      )
    )
  )
);

$bundleGridForm->setFields($detailFormFields);
```

As you can see, I'd like to only display an CheckboxSetField and as source `$HELP-NEEDED-HERE->VariationItems()->map()->toArray()` I'd like to use a realation (VariationItems) of the currently selected / clicked item.

The Problem is I don't know how to get this relation, because $this is of course referencing to the class, where my gridfield is on and not to the clicked item.

Perhapse the [handleItem()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.2/class-GridFieldDetailForm.html#_handleItem) function is what I need because it returns the [GridFieldDetailForm_ItemRequest](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.2/class-GridFieldDetailForm_ItemRequest.html) class where I can than call the [getRecord()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.2/class-GridFieldDetailForm_ItemRequest.html#_getRecord) function. But all of this presupposes that I  get the request form the gridfield to use the handleItem() function and I absolutely can't figure out how to get this record.

For any help I would be very grateful.

Best Regards

Comment: where do you need to get the current item? when editing an item? The edit form is generated in the current item, see `getCMSFields()` method of the Item class...

Comment: but not when I'm modifying the shown fields `$bundleGridForm->setFields($detailFormFields);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to answer my own question and for anyone who get also stuck here:

```
$bundleGridConfig
  ->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton');

$bundleGridForm = $bundleGridConfig->getComponentByType('GridFieldDetailForm');
// reset all fields, either you'r just adding new fields below
$bundleGridForm->setFields(FieldList::create());
$bundleGridForm->setItemEditFormCallback(function($form) {
  $record = $form->getRecord();

  // get the saved values 
  $availableVariations = $this->Items()->getExtraData('AvailableVariations', $record->ID);

  $form->Fields()->push(
    CheckboxSetField::create(
      'VariationList',
      'Verfügbare Variationen',
      $record->VariationItems(),
      // use the saved values as preset
      explode(',', $availableVariations['AvailableVariations'])
    )
  );

  // workaround for https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/4067
  $form->Fields()->push(
    HiddenField::create('ManyMany[AvailableVariations]', 'Verfügbare Variationen', $availableVariations['AvailableVariations'])
  );
});
```

the problem is that there is a [bug](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/4067), which prevents that CheckboxSetFields get written to the database. As a quick workaround, my CheckboxSetField is just a "pseudo-field" to display the checkboxes and the field to save the selected options to the database is a HiddenField.

All you have to do now, is to parse the selected options as a string and insert this string into the hidden field on any change of the CheckboxSetField.